# Flask importing files through Pycharm

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

Following microblog tutorial on Flask: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

In Pycharm, no matter how I structure or name the files, I cannot get the dev server to run if I separate the code and import the files. I also can't get it to inherit the codes no matter where I move the init, views, run files. The only way for me to get the server to run is to have all the commands execute on the same file. What am I doing wrong?

I have it setup as: 
Project 1 > app(directory) > tmp(directory) > run.py(file)

app(directory) > static(directory) > templates(directory) > **init**.py(file) > views.py(file) (I have tried different arrangements.)

Inside views.py: 
from app import app

Inside run.py:
from app import app

Inside **init**.py:
from flask import Flask
from app import views

(I have tried many different combinations such as from app import app.views. from app import views as app_views. I have also tried renaming the directories/files, nothing is working.)

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're doing. Does "app(directory) > tmp(directory) > run.py(file)" mean that you have `app/tmp/run.py`? Or does it mean that app, tmp, and run.py all live inside the same directory? You may also want to include contents of your files so that [people can try to recreate the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dirn -(Inside Directory and Project file) Project1/run.py Project1/tmp Project 1/app (Inside app directory) Project1/app/__init__.py Project1/app/views.py Project1/app/static Project1/app/templates

Comment: Please update the question. Comments are well suited for this type of content.

Answer (score 1):

1. Build the new project with PyCharm, it will create a virtual environment for you.  Then put these into a run.py in a root of your
   a project like that (don't forget to turn debugging mode off in prod)

   ```
       from app import create_app
       app = create_app()

       if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run(debug=True)
   ```

   2. Set up **init**.py file inside you 'app':

      ```
      def create_app(config_class=Config):
          app = Flask(__name__)
          app.config.from_object(Config)
          db.init_app(app)
          bcrypt.init_app(app)
          login_manager.init_app(app)
          mail.init_app(app)
      ```
   3. Store your credentials into Config class:

      class Config:
          SECRET_KEY = 'your key... '
          SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'your db...'
          SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
          MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.google.com'
          MAIL_PORT = 587
          MAIL_USE_TLS = True
          MAIL_USERNAME = 'your email' 
          MAIL_PASSWORD = 'email password'
   4. Structure your project, placing an empty **init**.py into each directory( accordingly to your architecture). Here is an example below, how to structure your project in Flask. It runs with no problem on

   `.
   ├── README.md
   ├── app
   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   ├── config.py
   │   ├── errors
   │   │   ├── 403.html
   │   │   ├── 404.html
   │   │   ├── 500.html
   │   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   │   └── handlers.py
   │   ├── main
   │   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   │   └── routes.py
   │   ├── models.py
   │   ├── posts
   │   │   ├── __init__.py
   │   │   ├── forms.py
   │   │   └── routes.py
   │   ├── site.db
   │   ├── static
   │   │   ├── main.css
   │   │   └── profile_pics
   │   │       ├── 3c4feb2bb50d90df.png
   │   │       ├── ba3d328163a8125e.png
   │   │       └── default.jpg
   │   ├── templates
   │   │   ├── about.html
   │   │   ├── account.html
   │   │   ├── create_post.html
   │   │   ├── home.html
   │   │   ├── layout.html
   │   │   ├── login.html
   │   │   ├── post.html
   │   │   ├── register.html
   │   │   ├── reset_request.html
   │   │   ├── reset_token.html
   │   │   └── user_posts.html
   │   └── users
   │       ├── __init__.py
   │       ├── forms.py
   │       ├── routes.py
   │       └── utils.py
   └── run.py`